# visual studio 2012 intellisense color

Tags: visual-studio, colors, intellisense, marker, indicator

What I want is to change the color for the indicator under letter A of ActionResult. I checked everything under Tools->Options->Text Editor. None of my current settings is set to this kind blue. Does anyone know where to change it, or is it non-customizable?

I'm a new user and cannot post image. My screenshot can be found at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibUSZ.png

I'm not sure if someone else has already asked this question or not, because i really don't know how to call this indicator.

Comment: Don't remember one like this, what does it do?

Comment: @Neolisk if you click on HomeController, this icon will show. and you can click on it or press CTRL + Period to rename HomeController for the whole solution or extract public method to generate new interface. I just realize it is because I have CodeRush installed.

Comment: But I do remember I have this indicator even before I install CodeRush. Say you are trying to use a class that its namespace has not been imported. This little indicator will show up and you can use CTRL + Period to import its namespace.

Comment: I don't think it is a font attribute so it may not be changeable from the text settings.   If you zoom in, it looks like a small blue rectangle.  If you change color schemes it doesn't change.

Comment: @Evan: if namespace is not imported, my VS will underline with blue, and show red rectangle with white inside, under the **last** letter of the class name. Did they change it in 2012?

Comment: @Neolisk If you zoom in my screenshot, it is a blue rectangle box. The inside color should depend on the background color of the text editor. It is the same in VS 2010.

Comment: @Evan: I understand. My point is that a **red** box under the **last** character indicates you need to import a namespace. What does a **blue** box under the **first** character mean? Is it how the same works in CodeRush?

Comment: @Neolisk I don't see the red box you are talking about. In both my VS2010 and VS2012, un-imported class has a red wavy underline and a blue box under the first letter.

Comment: @Evan: is it because you have CodeRush? In other words, if you disable/uninstall CodeRush, does it start working as it works for me?